# @Cacheable is working in Controller but not inside service

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-restcontroller, spring-cache

I have this strange problem in Spring Boot where `@Cacheable` is working in controller but not inside service. I can see GET call in Redis but not a PUT call.

This is working since it is inside controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/places")
public class PlacesController {

    private AwesomeService awesomeService;

    @Autowired
    public PlacesController(AwesomeService awesomeService) {
        this.awesomeService = awesomeService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/search")
    @Cacheable(value = "com.example.webservice.controller.PlacesController", key = "#query", unless = "#result != null")
    public Result search(@RequestParam(value = "query") String query) {
        return this.awesomeService.queryAutoComplete(query);
    }
}
```

But `@Cacheable` is not working when I do this in Service like this

```
@Service
public class AwesomeApi {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Cacheable(value = "com.example.webservice.api.AwesomeApi", key = "#query", unless = "#result != null")
    public ApiResult queryAutoComplete(String query) {
        try {
            return restTemplate.getForObject(query, ApiResult.class);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the `GET` call in Redis but not a `PUT` call.

Comment: It will never cache as you have `unless = "#result != null"` which means don't cache if the result is not `null`. So the actual result of the method call will never be cached. Basically `unless` is the opposite of `condition` on the `@Cachable` annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your caching should work fine as it is. Make sure that you have the `@EnableCaching` annotation and that your `unless` criteria is correct.

Right now, you're using `unless="#result != null"`,  which means it will cache the result, unless it's not `null`. This means that it will almost never cache, unless the `restTemplate.getForObject()` returns `null`, or when an exception occurs, because then you're also returning `null`.

I'm assuming that you want to cache each value, except `null`, but in that case you have to inverse your condition, e.g.:

```java
@Cacheable(
    value = "com.example.webservice.api.AwesomeApi",
    key = "#query",
    unless = "#result == null") // Change '!=' into '=='
```

Or, [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373323/cacheable-is-working-in-controller-but-not-inside-service/51374137?noredirect=1#comment89721172_51374137), in stead of reversing the condition, you can use `condition` in stead of `unless`:

```java
@Cacheable(
    value = "com.example.webservice.api.AwesomeApi",
    key = "#query",
    condition = "#result != null") // Change 'unless' into 'condition'
```

Comment: You can also rename `unless` to `condition` and keep what you have to make the intent a bit more clear

Comment: @StephaneNicoll You're right, didn't think about it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well it’s embarrassing that problem was such a small mistake. Adding to misery this happened because cache was already entered when I added that unless condition. So, I was not able to discover this issue. Anyway thank you very much for your help.